# Swift passing optional error in completion or calling failure closure

Tags: swift, swift3, closures

Almost all of us use API calls. So usually we make a request to the server and wait while app get back with response. When we got response we want to see if it's success or failure. Coming from the world Objective-C, I want to use the same construction on swift with `Success/Failure` blocks. But in most of examples I see that there is another way how the API call implemented. So instead of using additional failure block they use one completion block where programmers passing `result` and `error` as optional types.

So the Facade function that called API service checks if there is an error then app should trigger logic with showing some error alert.

The function I described looks like this:

```
func getCarList(_ completion: @escaping (_ result: [Car]?, _ error: Error?) -> (Void))
```

But my question is what is the better way passing error to completion handler or invoke failure closure instead. I understand that both can be useful. But maybe there is another advantage as well. Just want to make code swifty as much as I can.

Comment: Have you tried PromiseKit? I find it useful for handling the API calls as you return a Promise that is either successful or failed.

Comment: IMO, better way is passing one value of generic enum with value (with proper type) and error cases. That way you're sure that result is `either` success or failure, and you don't need to expect both being `nil` or both being not.

Comment: @user28434 yea got it thanks, if you can provide small example, it will be cool

Comment: @user28434 I understnad that you meant smth like this `enum Result<DataType> { case data(DataType) case error...` which is actually I want to achieve, but if you could provide this with explanation it will be perfect.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander, Something like [Alamofire.Result](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/0ac38d7e312e87aeea608d384e44401f3d8a6b3d/Source/Result.swift) or like [this lib](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) or [this one](https://github.com/Skogetroll/Result/).